# Creating EC2 instances in Terraform with worksapces

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm trying to figure out how to create different number of EC2 instances between two different Terraform workspaces. My approach is to have all Terraform code in one Github branch. I would like to have one `aws_instance` block that creates a different number of instances that are also different sized EC2 instances. I plan on using a a TFVARS file for separate environments in this case to specify what size instances are to be used. Any advice on how to best approach this scenario would be helpful. I am using Terraform version 0.12.26

Comment: That would be easy to do only if we had an example of code. The easiest way to do it would be by using the `terraform.workspace` with a ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do similar like this: (3 instances for `staging` and 1 for other workspaces)

```
resource "aws_instance" "cluster_nodes" {
  count                  = terraform.workspace == "staging" ? 3 : 1
  ami                    = var.cluster_aws_ami
  instance_type          = var.cluster_aws_instance_type
  # subnet_id            = aws_subnet.cluster_subnet[var.azs[count.index]].id
  subnet_id              = var.public_subnet_ids[count.index]
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.cluster_sg.id]
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.cluster_ssh_key.key_name
  iam_instance_profile   = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.cluster_ec2_instance_profile.name}"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  tags = {
    Name = "Cluster ${terraform.workspace} node-${count.index}"
  }
}
```